# SBT access to local Maven repositories

Tags: maven, sbt

I'm having difficulty configuring SBT to use my local maven repositories.  SBT is configured to use a proxy for external repositories which handles NTLM authentication for us, and this works OK.  I've attempted this:

```
resolvers ++= Seq("Local Maven Repository" at "file:///C:/java/apache-maven-3.0.3/repository",
                  "SIS Nexus Repository" at "http://linuxbuildserver-dev.sis.tv:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/",
                  "SIS 3rd Party Repository" at "http://linuxbuildserver-dev.sis.tv:8081/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty/"
              )
```

In order to access our local Maven repo and my own private cache; and the SBT resolvers task lists them OK.  However, on a compile, the resources I need are not accessed and the trace only mentions that public repos have been contacted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note, as you may have experienced issues:

Using a local maven cache as a repository can be dangerous (why we disabled it) if you have dependencies with version ranges.   Maven will download all the relevant Pom.xml files, but not the jar files.   In earlier versions of SBT (0.12.<4), this can cause Ivy to become confused and assume the jar should be in your maven cache when it is not, leading to resolution failure.

0.12.4 (now in RC2) should fix this issue.

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer eventually (somewhat unintuitively) - if I replace *resolvers* with *externalResolvers* then I get the compile to work.

Comment: Could you approve your answer if the solution worked for you?